# Filename not assigned to csv export in HighCharts on Mac

Tags: highcharts, safari, export-to-csv

I am using the [EXPORT-CSV plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/7/Export%20Data) for Highcharts to export data to csv.  (Thank you to the developers of this plugin!)  When testing in Safari on a Mac, however, the exported csv file does not take the filename as expected from

```
exporting: {
    filename: "FancyFileName"
}
```

and instead just uses the default Highcharts name "chart".  All the built-in export types do use the desired filename from Safari, and the csv also gets the desired filename from all the other standard browsers I have tested.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cqjvD/1070/).

How can Safari be convinced to use the filename I give it?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: That plugin has a bug tracker. I reported the issue - https://github.com/highcharts/export-csv/issues/86

Comment: Thanks Kacper.  Hope it can be resolved soon.

Answer (score 2):

The hard coded filename is coming from the php script written on the server. You can find that script on [php script for download of file with hardcoded file name](https://raw.github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/master/studies/csv-export/csv.php)

You can use that same code on your local machine server. To do that

1. create a php file on your local server.
2. copy the above code in it.
3. change url www.highcharts.com/studies/csv-export/csv.php in export.csv     library to your local server url.
4. change the name whatever you wish to using $_POST['variablename']

> Variable name should be pass when making post call from export.csv library and use in php file using $_POST

```
Highcharts.post(url, {
            data: content,
            name: name,
            type: MIME,
            extension: extension
        });
```

This is the code used in export.csv library for making post call. I have added extra parameter name to be used in my php script for dynamic filename.